# Dataframe Reshaping

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe that looks like.

```
    week_of  total_atc   rx_atc  non_rx_atc  custom_atc
0        15      43889  28950.0     14939.0      4979.0
1        16     114112  75477.0     38635.0     12471.0
2        17     127423  84852.0     42571.0     13945.0
```

Desired output

```
           15      16      17    
total_atc  43889   114112  127423
rx_atc     28950.0 75477.0  84852.0
non_rx_atc 14939   38635    42571
```

Tried something like

```
products_cart.pivot(index = 'week_of',columns='week_of',values='total_atc')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `set_index` + `transpose` (or its alias `T`):

```
res = df.set_index('week_of').T

print(res)

week_of          15        16        17
total_atc   43889.0  114112.0  127423.0
rx_atc      28950.0   75477.0   84852.0
non_rx_atc  14939.0   38635.0   42571.0
custom_atc   4979.0   12471.0   13945.0
```

If you need to drop `custom_atc` index, you can use `pd.DataFrame.drop`:

```
res = res.drop('custom_atc', 0)

print(res)

week_of          15        16        17
total_atc   43889.0  114112.0  127423.0
rx_atc      28950.0   75477.0   84852.0
non_rx_atc  14939.0   38635.0   42571.0
```